# Net Connection Issue using Visual Studio 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

i have developed a very simple program using vs2010 as under and found exception like unable to connect to the remote server. i also tried to update the visual studio and reinstalled it but problem still exist.i tried to connect the visual studio by option online privacy statement under help menu but it even cant open google home page. i think there is a problem in visual studio in my pc or any port is closed or some thing else is going wrong.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim doc As HtmlDocument = New HtmlDocument
    Dim a As HtmlDocument = New HtmlDocument
    Dim web As HtmlWeb = New HtmlWeb
    Private _loadURL As HtmlDocument

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        doc = web.Load("http://Dawn.com/")    ' (connection exception occur at this point)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Please show us the **full exception message** including stack trace. Telling us what the exception is "like" is not enough.

Comment: i found this . may be it is helpful for you to under stand ...............System.Net.WebException was unhandled
  Message=Unable to connect to the remote server
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
       at HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb.Get(Uri uri, String method, String path, HtmlDocument doc, IWebProxy proxy, ICredentials creds) in D:\Source\htmlagilitypack.new\Trunk\HtmlAgilityPack\HtmlWeb.cs:line 1355
      
   
       InnerException:

Comment: So can you browse to that url from your machine?

Comment: yes i can. is this a socket related problem.

Comment: intermediate window showed the following messages

Comment: A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in HtmlAgilityPack.dll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your network connection is connected through the PROXY SERVER or behind the proxy server. So you've to configure proxy server settings first for accessing any website or internet resource. The code below may help you.

```
Dim o As New MyWebService.Name
    Dim pr As New System.Net.WebProxy("100.0.1.1", 80)

    pr.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
    o.Proxy = pr

    Dim ds As New DataSet
    ds = o.GetMyData(Me.TextBox1.Text, "password")
    Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
```

You've to modify it according to your proxy configuration. (you can see proxy server address in browser settings or options)

Comment: thanks alot . . . wow you are awsome. . problem is solved.i am doing my degree project and was badly stucked. many many thanks from the deep of my heart.